# Unable to include javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii

I am trying to implement [Supersized](http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/) slider with my Yii project. In order to implement I have to implement some javascript in the view. So I decided to go with the registerscript method. But I think I am not able to initialized the directory location of the images. Could you help me

My code is

```
<?php   

$script= <<<EOD
jQuery(function($){             
    $.supersized({
        slide_interval          :7000,  // Length between transitions
    transition              :1,     // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
    transition_speed    :1000,  // Speed of transition
    slide_links     :'blank',// Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
    slides          :[// Slideshow Images
                $directory = Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/uploads/';
                $images = glob($directory . "*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,PNG}", GLOB_BRACE);
                foreach($images as $image)
                echo "{image : 'http://localhost/uploads/" . $image . "', title : '" .$image . "'},";
                ]   
            });
            });
EOD;
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('customFnc', $script, CClientScript::POS_READY);?>
```

Comment: I am getting undefind directory error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This Way..

```
<script>
            jQuery(function($){             
                $.supersized({
                  slide_interval          :7000,  // Length between transitions
                  transition              :1,     // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
                  transition_speed    :1000,  // Speed of transition
                  slide_links     :'blank',// Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
                  slides          :[// Slideshow Images
     <?php
                            $directory = Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/uploads/';
                            $images = glob($directory . "*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,PNG}", GLOB_BRACE);
                            foreach($images as $image)
                            echo "{image : 'http://localhost/uploads/" . $image . "', title : '" .$image . "'},"; ?>

                            ]   
                        });
                        });
            </script>
```

Comment: You should not be using absolute paths (http://localhost) , you should use Yii base URL `Yii::app()->request->baseUrl` which points to the root (you could also use `getcwd()`). The reason is that when you upload it your live server you will have to find and replace all these paths. Using base URL makes the application more portable

Comment: I am agree and I have tried both method but none of them is working. Could you please help.

Comment: @Neeraj or eskimo, Could you guys help me with the images

Comment: first check the link to the images, run your code from the browser and use "Inspect Element" to check the images, if the images are loaded, then there is certainly some problem in the jquery code.....